# How to make the application run in the background, as soon as the device starts/restarts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

So, I have an alarm application which works good and behaves normally as long as the device remains online until the alarm time.

Problem is, let's say I ran out of battery, or I just want to restart the device... the alarm won't fire upon its time.

I tried something like:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Utils.set_alarms(context);
        }
    }
}
```

In my BroadcastReceiver... but doesn't seem to work. Oh, and it's registered in the AndroidManifest too...:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.AlarmReceiver" // The receiver which starts the alarm activity.
        android:enabled="true" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BootCompletedReceiver" // The receiver which is supposed to set the alarms after the device is online again.
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But doesn't work... help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the permission to receive boot completed to your manifest. See [Manifest Permission: RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Comment: Do I need to add something to ask the user if I can receive the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED action?

Comment: Well, this is considered a dangerous install permission (not runtime) so the user will be warned at installation and can choose not to install, but at runtime the permission is considered granted by installation (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Add below `permission` and `actions`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.BootCompletedReceiver" // The receiver which is supposed to set the alarms after the device is online again.
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <!-- used for restart or reboot -->
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
         <!-- Used for cold boot -->
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />//cold start
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Yeah, the "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />" was already there... and I tried the QUICKBOOT_POWERON thing, but doesn't seem to work yet... any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.